# A simple way to sum a result from UNION in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, union

I have a union of three tables (t1, t2, t3).
Each rerun exactly the same number of records, first column is `id`, second `amount`:

```
1  10
2  20
3  20

1  30
2  30
3  10

1  20
2  40
3  50
```

Is there a **simple** way in SQL to sum it up, i.e. to only get:

```
1   60
2   80
3   80
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
select id, sum(amount) from (
    select id,amount from table_1 union all
    select id,amount from table_2 union all
    select id,amount from table_3
) x group by id
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to accomplish this in a view, but sub-queries aren't allowed in views. Is there an alternative?

Comment: make the subquery another view

Answer (score 16):

```
SELECT id, SUM(amount) FROM
(
    SELECT id, SUM(amount) AS `amount` FROM t1 GROUP BY id
  UNION ALL
    SELECT id, SUM(amount) AS `amount` FROM t2 GROUP BY id
) `x`
GROUP BY `id`
```

I groupped each table and unioned because i think it might be faster, but you should try both solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Subquery:

```
SELECT id, SUM(amount)
FROM ( SELECT * FROM t1
       UNION ALL SELECT * FROM t2
       UNION ALL SELECT * FROM t3
     )
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Note: you shouldn't use select * in this case.

Comment: Note 2: I bet mysql will ask you to assign alias to subquery

Comment: @David: For sure, my bad.  Probably doesn't matter if id and amount are the only two columns, but what are the chances of that?
@zerkms: Also true.

Comment: exactly.  And even if there are only id and amount for now, there's no sense in shooting yourself in the foot when you add a third column in 6 months... :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if MySQL uses common table expression but I would do this in postgres:

```
WITH total AS(
              SELECT id,amount AS amount FROM table_1 UNION ALL
              SELECT id,amount AS amount FROM table_2 UNION ALL
              SELECT id,amount AS amount FROM table_3
             )
SELECT id, sum(amount)
  FROM total
```

I think that should do the trick as well.

Comment: As was mentioned. This requires a group by id.

Answer (score 1):

As it's not very clear from previous answers, remember to give aliases (on MySQL/MariaDb) or you'll get error:

**Every derived table must have its own alias**

```
select id, sum(amount) from (
    select id,amount from table_1 union all
    select id,amount from table_2 union all
    select id,amount from table_3
) AS 'aliasWhichIsNeeded'
 group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes!!! Its okay! Thanks!!!!
My code finishing:

```sql
SELECT SUM(total) 
FROM ( 
        (SELECT 1 as id, SUM(e.valor) AS total  FROM entrada AS e)
    UNION 
        (SELECT 1 as id, SUM(d.valor) AS total FROM despesa AS d)
    UNION 
        (SELECT 1 as id, SUM(r.valor) AS total FROM recibo AS r WHERE r.status = 'Pago')
)  x group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      BANKEMPNAME,  workStation, SUM (CALCULATEDAMOUNT) FROM(
SELECT      BANKEMPNAME, workStation, SUM(CALCULATEDAMOUNT) AS CALCULATEDAMOUNT,SALARYMONTH
FROM        dbo.vw_salaryStatement
WHERE       (ITEMCODE  LIKE 'A%') 
GROUP BY    BANKEMPNAME,workStation, SALARYMONTH
union all
SELECT      BANKEMPNAME, workStation,  SUM(CALCULATEDAMOUNT) AS CALCULATEDAMOUNT,SALARYMONTH
FROM        dbo.vw_salaryStatement
WHERE       (ITEMCODE  NOT LIKE 'A%')
GROUP BY    BANKEMPNAME, workStation, SALARYMONTH) as t1
WHERE       SALARYMONTH BETWEEN '20220101' AND '20220131'
group by    BANKEMPNAME,  workStation
order by    BANKEMPNAME asc
```

IN MSSQL You can write this way, But Doing **UNION ALL** THE Column should be the same for both ways.

I have given this example So that you can understand the process...

Comment: @EricAya I have already changed the letter please check. Thank you