# MySQL with monthly tables and monthly joins

Tags: mysql, select, join

I am an trainee as a software developer. I have a question: How can I access to multiple tables with select and join?

The name of the main-tables are like:

```
logs_0215
logs_0315

logs_mmyy  ->  m = month; y = year
```

The name of the timestamp-tables are like:

```
timestamp_0215
timestamp_0315

timestamp_mmyy  ->  m = month; y = year
```

My query which works only for one table is like:

```
SELECT a.id, b.stamp, c.name AS portal, d.name AS company, e.name AS protocol, a.value
FROM logs_0315 AS a
LEFT JOIN timestamp_0315 AS b ON a.time_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN portale AS c ON a.portal_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN companies AS d ON a.comp_id = d.id
LEFT JOIN proocols AS e ON a.prot_id = e.id
WHERE b.stamp BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-06-25'
```

How can I access to all tables which contains logs_mmyy with its timestamp?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Yours sincerely
t.koelpin

Comment: you can't, not without dynamically building/executing query strings. your system SHOULD be redesigned to a SINGLE table which contains a `timestamp` field, from which you can trivially extract month/year information, e.g. `select count(*) from logs where year(timestamp)=2015 and month(timestamp)=2`. then it's also easy to let the DB engine partition your table for you, without having to deal with littering your db with pointless "duplicate" tables.

Comment: Why SHOULD I REDESIGN the table? What's the reason for?  I decided the format, because the search-speed is with the one-table very slow. I decided to split the data into a monthly table for an higher performance. The one-table contained over 100.000.000 Rows!  I just thought of a multiple SELECT with concatting the tables. Is this way possible?

Comment: that's what indexes are for, and server-level partitioning. there's no way to do something like `select * from time_*`, since wildcards and "dynamic" table/field names are not permitted, period, in queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to *explicitly* identify each table; each table has to be identified by name in a `FROM` clause. SQL does not support wildcard pattern matching for identifiers (table names, column names, etc.).

Given what you've posted, it looks like you could use a `UNION ALL` set operator to combine results from multiple SELECT statements as a single query:

```
  SELECT a.id, ...
    FROM logs_0315 a 
    LEFT JOIN timestamp_0315 AS b ON a.time_id = b.id
         ...
   WHERE b.stamp BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-06-25'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a.id, ...
    FROM logs_0415 a 
    LEFT JOIN timestamp_0415 AS b ON a.time_id = b.id
         ...
   WHERE b.stamp BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-06-25'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a.id, ...
    FROM logs_0515 a 
    LEFT JOIN timestamp_0515 AS b ON a.time_id = b.id
         ...
   WHERE b.stamp BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-06-25'
```

If you need an `ORDER BY` on the combined result, you can enclose each `SELECT` statement in parens. Like this:

```
 ( SELECT a.id, ...
     FROM logs_0315 a 
     LEFT JOIN timestamp_0315 AS b ON a.time_id = b.id
          ...
    WHERE b.stamp BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-06-25'
 )
 UNION ALL
 ( SELECT a.id, ...
     FROM logs_0415 a 
     LEFT JOIN timestamp_0415 AS b ON a.time_id = b.id
          ...
    WHERE b.stamp BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-06-25'
 )
 UNION ALL
 ( SELECT a.id, ...
     FROM logs_0515 a 
      LEFT JOIN timestamp_0515 AS b ON a.time_id = b.id
          ...
    WHERE b.stamp BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-06-25'
 )
 ORDER BY ...
```

---

In order to make this dynamic, to get all tables of the pattern `logs_mmyy`, you could query `information_schema.tables` and get the list of tables, and then use that to dynamically generate a statement as above. This approach requires (at a minimum) two separate SQL statements. It's not possible to achieve this type of result in a single SQL statement.

Comment: I hope this is the solution what I wanted. I'll testing it tomorrow. If it works, this thread is soluted then ...

Comment: This is the solution what I wanted for. In the combination with [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387734/a-simple-way-to-sum-a-result-from-union-in-mysql[/link] I solved the problem. Thank you so much!