# Sum union calculated value in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

I have two SELECT statements that I'd like to sum. Both queries work fine but I'm not able to SUM the output of total. I tried following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387734/a-simple-way-to-sum-a-result-from-union-in-mysql) but unable to SUM by wrapping the query in `select id, sum(amount) from ( )`

```
SELECT "patient_profiles"."id", count(distinct recommendations.id) AS total
FROM "patient_profiles" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  "recommendations" ON "recommendations"."patient_profile_id" = "patient_profiles"."id" 
GROUP BY "patient_profiles"."id"

UNION

SELECT "patient_profiles"."id", count(distinct patient_profile_potential_doctors.id) AS total
FROM "patient_profiles" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "patient_profile_potential_doctors" ON "patient_profile_potential_doctors"."patient_profile_id" = "patient_profiles"."id"       
GROUP BY "patient_profiles"."id"
```

Comment: You said, "unable to SUM by wrapping the query in `select id, sum(amount) from ( )`" do you get an error? you change amount to total right?

Answer (score 9):

```
    Select ID, sum(Total) from  
      (
        SELECT "patient_profiles"."id" [ID], count(distinct recommendations.id) AS total
        FROM "patient_profiles" 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN 
          "recommendations" ON "recommendations"."patient_profile_id" = "patient_profiles"."id" 
        GROUP BY "patient_profiles"."id"

        UNION

        SELECT "patient_profiles"."id" [ID], count(distinct patient_profile_potential_doctors.id) AS total
        FROM "patient_profiles" 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN "patient_profile_potential_doctors" ON "patient_profile_potential_doctors"."patient_profile_id" = "patient_profiles"."id"       
        GROUP BY "patient_profiles"."id"
) x
    group by ID
```

Comment: I get the following error using postgresql `ERROR:  cannot subscript type integer because it is not an array`